# Swift + AppCode format for alignment type

Tags: swift, appcode

What I want is this

[image]

But when I do formatting automatically from appcode those variables end up like this

[image]

When I look into their coding style for swift, I can't seem to find the configuration to change this behavior.

Anyone know a way to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, manage to find that option

[image]

When uncheck, it works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

best way to do this is by using the shortcut 
first select all code 
then press control + i 
and it should automatically reform the code to swifty one

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion. I have try control + I, it is only remove empty indent line. But it isn't solve my problem.